# what is select_related attribute in dajngo generic class,can someone explain what this implies?

Tags: django, django-views, django-generic-views

```
class PostDetail(SelectRelatedMixin,generic.DetailView):
model=models.Post
select_related=('user','group')
```

This is the snippet and the instructor told its for associating user with post and the group with post.
what exactly does this implies and how its get associated?

Comment: https://django-braces.readthedocs.io/en/latest/other.html#selectrelatedmixin